# Design table missing in SQL Server Management Studio context menu

Tags: sql-server, ssms

There is no design table or edit data in the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio, any ideas? I have full privileges and its running in a admin context.

Comment: which version of the SSMS are you using?

Comment: You can find the hotfix overhere. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213508/sql-server-2016-express-management-studio-cannot-design-a-new-or-existing-table/38392890#38392890